# Permutations/Combinations where only certain elements can be re-ordered with certain other elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am sorry if this is posted the wrong sub-forum, but my math knowledge is limited and so I am unsure where else to post.

I am wondering how to calculate the number of possible versions of a series of characters, where only some characters in the series can vary.

> 5NMB RTTM 8L60 9P7U AJQW 9889
>
> 5-N-M-B **R**/**L**-T-T-**M**/**N** 8-L-**6**/**G**-**0**/**O** 9-P-**7**/**4**-U   A-**J**/**3**-Q-**W**/**V** 9-**8**/**B**-**8**/**B**-9

Therefore, the following are possible (characters in bold are variations on the original series):

> 5NMB **L**TT**M** 8L**60** 9P**4**U A**J**Q**W** 9**88**9
>
> 5NMB **R**TT**M** 8L**60** 9P**7**U A**J**Q**W** 9**BB**9
>
> 5NMB **L**TT**N** 8L**GO** 9P**4**U A**3**Q**V** 9**88**9

But the following is NOT:

> 5NMB **N**TT**O** 8L**60** 9P**7**U A**B**Q**B** 9**3V**9

1. How many different combinations are possible where **only bold
   characters** can vary and they can vary only with the **bold
   character** that follows them with a "/"? Is there a formula for
   this? Answered kindly by JMoravitz.
2. How would I go about generating all these different combinations
   using excel or similar software?

I hope this makes sense. [I have attached a picture of this question formatted in a way which might be clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1bD3.png)

I am new to the forum so forgive me if my posting etiquette or anything is off-point-- and please let me know so my posts are better in the future!

I look forward to your responses.

Comment: For each of the bold portions, **pick** which of the **two** options is actually used.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  With $k$ occurrences of two choices available each, we get a total number of $2^k$ outcomes.

Comment: Thanks! While this would give 2^9 (512) combinations, how would I go about generating these combinations themselves? I.e. producing a list of these 512 combinations on excel or wolfram or something. I will edit my question to make this clearer!

Comment: That sounds more like a coding question than a math question, but the short easy answer is that you can run nested loops, if the first time in a loop use the first corresponding choice, otherwise use the second corresponding choice...  Alternatively, you can describe each by a binary number,. a digit of $0$ corresponding to the first choice in the respective slot and a digit of $1$ corresponding to the alternate choice, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Note that only nine places of your sequence can vary that too only with 2 choices. The other letters need not to be permuted.

Hence for each of these places there are two choices to choose from , which will lead to different permutation every time.  So using the "*product of rule*" we get the answer as $2^9=512$